# Link binary with static library in xcconfig

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, xcode5

I have an Xcode project that is essentially a single app that gets built into several almost identical targets. I have moved nearly all build configuration settings in central places, but I cannot figure out how to move linking against a static library (libMantle.a) to the xcconfig. I have tried the `-framework` and `-l` flags, like I'm using for various other libraries, but they don't work. Is there a way to get .a files out of the Link Binary with Libraries pane, so I don't need to keep all the targets in sync manually?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out...

Let's say you want to link against the file `libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a`. There are basically three things you should have in your .xcconfig to get it working.

First you want to make sure you have the path to the library in your search path. Then you need to pass *two* flags to make the linker happy `-L` with the path to the directory, and `-l` with the library.

Putting it all together will get you something like:

```
LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/Google Analytics"
OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -L"$(SRCROOT)/Vendor/Google Analytics" -lGoogleAnalyticsServices
```

*(You would need to adjust for your relative paths)*

The most helpful thing in getting this sorted out was the Log Navigator (command+8 in Xcode). By putting the static library in the Build Phases `Link Binary With Libraries` panel and doing a successful build, you can look details of the linker step in the logs, and see how it was passing the Analytics library to the compiler. From there it's just replicating those flags in the xcconfig.

Comment: May I ask how you handle source files for various targets? Do you add them to xcconfig files as well? Is that even possible?

Comment: Target-specific xcconfig files get pretty messy, since there's no real good way of doing it. I rarely have projects whose targets have drastically different library dependencies, though. What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a project with 9 targets. I only need those targets to set ONE SINGLE preprocessor macro for each target. Mainly to change the base API URL for different environments (development, staging, production). So I would love to have an single file that specifies the base build configuration including all the source files and resources to copy.

Comment: I think I answered your question in this: https://gist.github.com/farski/9763168 or at least how I generally handle that. No promises that it's the best way or even a good way. Works for me, though.